# Configure Ember to remove brackets from url with array of ids

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-data

In my Ember application I'm referencing a couple of objects which are not already retrieved and cached from the server. Ember is getting the data which it needs in a single request with all the ids in the url with `[]` next to it. But my Java-backend does not handle that correctly. Example: `/rest/sites?ids[]=1&ids[]=3&ids[]=5`

Is there a way to configure Ember to remove those brackets? Like this: `/rest/sites?ids=1&ids=3&ids=5`

See my example.

Response from earlier call:

```
{
  "client": {
    "name": "test",
    "sites": [ 1, 3, 5 ]
  }
}
```

my template:

```
{{#each controllers.sites}}
  <h2>{{name}}</h2>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I [found](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that the brackets come from the AJAX-settings of jQuery. 
There is a jQuery setting you can configure to remove the square brackets from the serialized URL:

```
$.ajaxSettings({ traditional = true });
```